# PowerBI Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod Extract Exception Trace

Tags: powershell, powerbi

While invoking PowerBI Rest APIs using the Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod exception trace is getting abstracted, tried accessing it through $_.Exception.Message still it doesn't print the actual exception message/trace, has little experience in Powershell it should be straight forward to extract the exception message.

```
try{
 Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "url...."
}catch {
 Write-Host $_.Exception.Message -Foreground "Red"
 Write-Host $_.ScriptStackTrace -Foreground "DarkGray"
 throw "Exception During PowerBI CmdLets!!"
}
```

Exception:

```
Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod : One or more errors occurred.
At D:\a\r1\a\lib\scripts\updateparameters.ps1:53 char:2
+  Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod -Url "groups/$($workspace.id)/datasets/$($d ...
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (Microsoft.Power...werBIRestMethod:InvokePowerBIRestMethod) 
[Invoke-PowerBIRestMethod], AggregateException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : One or more errors 
occurred.,Microsoft.PowerBI.Commands.Profile.InvokePowerBIRestMethod
```

Comment: Have you tried the Resolve-PowerBIError cmdlet? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/power-bi/overview?view=powerbi-ps#troubleshooting-errors